# How does Niftynet handle multiple-gpu training

Tags: niftynet

I'm using Niftynet to train a CNN using 2 GPUs. As I understand, each GPU is trained independently as I get two loss values per iteration. Are the results of both GPUs combined at inference time?
I used to believe that using multiple-gpus reduces the training time but in Niftynet it doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, correct. It does reduce training time at my case. Notice, that the batch size doubles by using multiple GPUs.

For example, if your `batch size = 2`, after using multiple gpu it means that every gpu will have `batch size = 2`. So your final batch size will be 4.